# Use windows authentication with Active directory Lightweight directory services?

Tags: asp.net, adlds

I'm trying to use AD Lightweight Directory Services for user authentication in ASP.net application and dont want to use Forms authentication. Is there any way to authenticate it using windows authentication.

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

[How To: Use Windows Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx)

[How To: Use Forms Authentication with Active Directory in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998360.aspx)

Edit:
This worked for me:

```
<!-- web.config -->
...
<system.web>
...     
    <compilation debug="true">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>

    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
        <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
    </customErrors>

    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"/>  

    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
        <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
</system.web>
...
```

and then in code

```
//page.cs
...
string userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
...
```

You should be able to do some custom code with for example [DirectoryEntry Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.aspx), like [Enumerating Users and Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa772126%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Here You can find more about [Using Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa772138%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I want to use AD LDS to authenticate the user and dont want to use forms authentication.

Comment: @AshokD : I added an example